# Android updating values in mysql by row

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my android app. When i update the scores of teams, everything in the database updates. How do i set this to update one row at a time. Can i update this by id? if so how can i do it? Thank you!

PHP

```
<?php 

 $teamone = $_POST["teamone"];
 $teamtwo = $_POST["teamtwo"];
 $teamonepts = $_POST["teamonepts"];
 $teamtwopts = $_POST["teamtwopts"];



 require_once('init.php');


 $sql = "UPDATE matches SET teamone = '$teamone',  teamonepts = '$teamonepts', teamtwo = '$teamtwo', teamtwopts = '$teamtwopts'";


 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo 'Updated';
 }else{
 echo 'Failed';
 }


 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Here is my android code

```
else if(method.equals("send"))
        {

            String teamone = params[1];
            String teamonepts = params[2];
            String teamtwo = params[3];
            String teamtwopts = params[4];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(send_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode
                        ("teamone", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamone, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("teamonepts", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamonepts, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("teamtwo", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamtwo, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("teamtwopts", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamtwopts, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return "Data Sent";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my table

[image: Here is my table]

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column='value' WHERE ID=1`

Comment: Works, But how do i do it if i want to id to go to the next column after update

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ID of the row you want to update in your SQL query.

In PHP it should be like:

```
<?php

$m_id = $_POST["m_id"];
$teamone = $_POST["teamone"];
$teamtwo = $_POST["teamtwo"];
$teamonepts = $_POST["teamonepts"];
$teamtwopts = $_POST["teamtwopts"];

// ... your code ...

$sql = "UPDATE matches SET teamone = '$teamone',  teamonepts = '$teamonepts', teamtwo = '$teamtwo', teamtwopts = '$teamtwopts' WHERE m_id = '$m_id'";

// ... your code ...
```

And in Android:

```
// ... your code ...
String m_id = params[0]; // I assume you have an ID as first element of params
String teamone = params[1];
String teamonepts = params[2];
String teamtwo = params[3];
String teamtwopts = params[4];

// ... your code ...

String data = URLEncoder.encode("m_id", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(m_id, "UTF-8")+"&"+
URLEncoder.encode("teamone", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamone, "UTF-8")+"&"+
URLEncoder.encode("teamonepts", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamonepts, "UTF-8")+"&"+
URLEncoder.encode("teamtwo", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamtwo, "UTF-8")+"&"+
URLEncoder.encode("teamtwopts", "UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(teamtwopts, "UTF-8");

// ... your code ...
```

Comment: sorry i didnt see this answer. It doesnt work sir. If i put the m_id it wont update

Comment: @osoda Can you get little bit more details about `params` variable in Android code: what's in there and how you get it?

Comment: what sir? i dont understand

Comment: In your Android code you have `String teamone = params[1];` etc. Can you explain what value do you have in `params[0]`?

Comment: params[0] i set to method. In which it tells if the user will login or update

Comment: To update only one record in db you need to know key / primary key of the record. In your case I assume primary key is `m_id`. You need to know `m_id` and send it with your POST data (m_id, teamone, teamtwo, etc). Can you fetch `m_id` from DB before sending request to PHP?

Comment: I got it now. But my problem is it always gives me failed to update. Even if i run my php on my browser the echo statement says failed

Comment: Replace your `echo 'Failed';` with `echo 'Failed: ' . mysqli_error($con);` to make your error more verbose to understand what's going on

Comment: Thank you so much @krlv i got it working now. got my error on my php